# RequiredFieldValidator CSS changes everything but font-size

Tags: asp.net, css

I've searched everywhere regarding this but I can't find an answer.

Writing an ASP webform I can't get the error messages to behave. It seems like I can style everything except for the font-size. I can change colour, padding etc no problem, but font-size does nothing. Any ideas?

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
              ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
              runat="server" 
              ControlToValidate="TitleDropDown" 
              ErrorMessage="Title is required" 
              Display="Dynamic" 
              CssClass="rfv" 
              ForeColor="" 
              EnableTheming="True">
```

css looks like...

```
.rfv
{
    padding-left:10px;
    color:Blue;
    font-size:x-small;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial;
    font-weight:lighter;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: FYI ... this is ASP.NET WebForms not ASP Classic.

Comment: This could be a specificity issue, but it's hard to tell. Try increasing the specificity by adding the ID: `#RequiredFieldValidator1.rfv {}`

Comment: @alpaca lips: Thanks but I do this wont I need one for each RequireFieldValidatorX?

Comment: I see your point. Try using a descendant selector: `#yourFormId .rfv {}` Or, for ultimate specificity: `body .rfv {}`. If neither of those work, then it's not a specificity issue.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either unfortunately. It still only lets control colour, not size.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inline styling in the control declaration.

Required field validator wont support a style property when showing error messages.

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ErrorMessage="required" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="24" EnableTheming=true    runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

This will work. It is tested.

Comment: Does this mean I have to add the font size manually to each field? I cannot use CSS?

Comment: @Brian: Thanks, this is really weird. Does everyone have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, using the 'starts-with' css selector:

```
    [id^=Required]
    {
        font-size:6px;    
    }
```